# Meteor subscription ready performance

Tags: performance, mongodb, meteor

I have a performance issue with Meteor subscriptions, and the time taken from subscribing to the subscription to be ready.

I subscribe to three collections, and the subscription onReady events don't get called until around 4 seconds later (they all take exactly the same time to return call onReady).

Logging on the server shows that the results are returned from the database in only a few milliseconds. The server I am running localhost, so the network latency / speed isn't an issue (I get the same problem when loading from a staging server).

As far as I can see, I do not have any blocking code, and the timeline shows lots of idle time, so I don't know what causes this long delay.

The user data and channels collections are quite small, and the schedules is around 1mb (I'm not sure how to get the exact size, but when I log and minify the json it's 1mb), but when I test to return only a small number of objects (5, rather than the usual 40) the load is still slow (5 takes ~2000ms, 40 takes ~3000ms)

Any suggestions, tips or gotchas appreciated.

[image: Timelines — the userData, channels and schedules are the subscriptions time (from subscribe to onReady)]

[image: Network timeline in the load period]

[image: Kadira response time dashboard]

[image: Some stats from my Mongo dashboard, although these are returning data to the server in a matter of milliseconds, so doesn't seem to be the problem]

Comment: Can you show (a) the network tab as well, (b) your publication code, and (c) the number and size of the documents being published.

Comment: I also recommend installing Kadira to get a detailed view of your app's performance.